# Как делается режим Картинка в картинке (PIP) в Android Studio для API 21-23?

Tags: java, android

Вопрос по большей части из любопытства, хотя мне бы это очень сильно помогло кое в чем.
Есть в маркете немало приложений для просмотра видео с YouTube. И не редко у них есть одна интересная функция - просмотр видео в отдельном маленьком окне поверх всех остальных приложений, типа вот так:
 [image: Плавающее окно проигрывателя]

Поидее это называется режим картинка в картинке (PictureInPicture). В гугловской документации о нем есть статейка, но проблема в том, что он работает только начиная с API 24 и новее. У меня телефон с Android 6 (API 23).

И вот вопрос: как они это сделали? Скриншот выше с моего телефона. Мне бы хотелось что-то подобное себе сделать в приложении с API 21+.

И еще, может кто знает, как вообще делаются всякие эти "плавающие" штуки?
Например, есть в приложениях Musixmatch (если кто видел) или в ES Проводнике есть плавающие, так сказать, иконки.
Если, например, ES проводник запущен и свёрнут, и ты скачал какой-нибудь mp3 файл, то даже если ты в другом приложении или на главном экране, у края экрана поверх всех приложений вылезает маленькая "плавающая" иконка проводника, нажмешь на неё и открывается ES на главной и пишет "У вас новый аудиотрек"... 
Как подобное можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятен вопрос, что значит как это делается? Вроде в мануале [исчерпывающе описан PiP](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture) как применяется и создается - что еще нужно то?

Обычно, фича, которая появляется в новых версиях Android'а реализуется в младших моделях с помощью [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/). Для PiP нет пока суппорт либы, так что пока для младших версий PiP не работает.

В усеченном варианте, когда на экране показывается одновременно несколько приложений/Activity это т.н. [MultiWindow](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) - это относительно просто, кодировать почти ничего не надо - надо только немного переписать манифест приложения, типа:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        >
        <layout
            android:defaultWidth="480dp"
            android:defaultHeight="800dp"
            android:minWidth="240dp"
            android:minHeight="320dp"
            android:gravity="top|end"
            />
    </activity>
```

Вторая часть вопроса про перетаскиваемые иконки. В самом простом варианте, можно остановиться на [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton), чтобы его еще и таскать по экрану надо смотреть в сторону функции [Drag-And-Drop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop)